# How to center Text or FormattedText in a VBox and let text start at the same position in every line?

Tags: flexbox, sapui5

Im using a VBox and I got multiple lines of text or FormattedText with HTML. The goal is to center this text and let it start and end at the same position in every line.

Here is a short example:

TextTextText

TextText

TextTextTextText

Text

Centering the text works without a problem, I use alignItems="Center" for that. What is not working is that the text starts at the same position in every line. I included in image to show you the problem. The last line should start at the same position as the other two lines.

[image: Last text ist not beginning at the same position as the other 2 elements]

To solve the problem, I tried different settings for justifyContent and alignItems, but nothing provided the result I was hoping for. So I hope you guys see what I'm missing here or doing wrong. Thank you for any help!

Comment: If i understand you correctly, you are having a layout issue. Try using a layout like the BlockLayout and see whether that resolves your issue.
[Refer this link for the SAP sample app](https://sapui5.hana.ondemand.com/#/entity/sap.ui.layout.BlockLayout/sample/sap.ui.layout.sample.BlockLayoutLinkTitle)

Comment: You did understand me! :) Thanks for sharing the link, I played around with it and until now it was exactly what I was looking for

Answer (score 1):

The first part of your question confuses me since your short example doesn't **end** at the same position.

Though I think you want something like this (assuming you have 1 text):

```
<HBox width="100%" justifyContent="Center">
    <VBox width="50%">
        <Text text="Testtesttesttestest..Testtesttesttestest..Testtesttesttestest..Testtesttesttestest..Testtesttesttestest..Testtesttesttestest..Testtesttesttestest..Testtesttesttestest..Testtesttesttestest..Testtesttesttestest..Testtesttesttestest..Testtesttesttestest..Testtesttesttestest..Testtesttesttestest..Testtesttesttestest..Testtesttesttestest..Testtesttesttestest..Testtesttesttestest..Testtesttesttestest..Testtesttesttestest..Testtesttesttestest..Testtesttesttestest..Testtesttesttestest..Testtesttesttestest..Testtesttesttestest..Testtesttesttestest..Testtesttesttestest..Testtesttesttestest..Testtesttesttestest..Testtesttesttestest..Testtesttesttestest..Testtesttesttestest..Testtesttesttestest..Testtesttesttestest..Testtesttesttestest..Testtesttesttestest..Testtesttesttestest..Testtesttesttestest..Testtesttesttestest..Testtesttesttestest..Testtesttesttestest..Testtesttesttestest..Testtesttesttestest..Testtesttesttestest..Testtesttesttestest..Testtesttesttestest..Testtesttesttestest..Testtesttesttestest..Testtesttesttestest..Testtesttesttestest..Testtesttesttestest..Testtesttesttestest..Testtesttesttestest..Testtesttesttestest..Testtesttesttestest..Testtesttesttestest..Testtesttesttestest..Testtesttesttestest..Testtesttesttestest..Testtesttesttestest..Testtesttesttestest..Testtesttesttestest..."/>
    </VBox>
</HBox>
```

The `HBox` takes the entire width and the `justifyContent=Center` makes sure that it's content is centered horizontally.
By defining the `width` of the `VBox` you can define how wide the text has to be displayed.

Answer (score 0):

```
alignItems="Start"
```

or

```
alignItems="Baseline"
```

should work